# SceneKit: Rotate a node according to device motion data while making it accelerate in its direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, scenekit

I've been fiddling with SceneKit recently and I wanted to make the following thing:

When creating a Game template from Xcode, you get a scene with a ship. 
I wanted to animate this ship and orient it according to the relative position of my iPhone after I tap the screen. So for instance, if I hold my iPhone horizontally, tap the screen, this takes the reference attitude of my horizontal iPhone. Then, when I lift it (changing the pitch), I want the ship to orient itself as such.

I've been trying to change my ship node eulerAngles with the attitude pitch yaw and roll as in the following:

```
CMAttitude * attitude = deviceMotion.attitude
_ship.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-attitude.pitch, attitude.yaw, attitude.roll);
```

Whenever I do that, the ship goes back to its original position in the scene. I can't seem to understand how to give it a speed in the direction it's facing without making it reset to its original position when I change its eulerAngles.

Ideally, the ship would have some sort of engine power accelerating it in the direction it's facing, while it would still be affected by gravity. How should I do that? Thanks!